# How to pass User entered textbox values from view in JSON format to Controller action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I need to pass a Html helper Textbox value that users enter in View to a controller action method as a parameter . When i am calling the controller action method from Javascript function using Jquery passing the textbox value in JSON format, the values are coming properly in JSON as i found in firebug/fiddler, but the values are not getting passed from my Textbox in view as a parameter to controller action method. The parameter is displaying as null when i debug the controller action method.

Comment: Post some code, it would be useful..

Answer (score 0):

The framework will try to fill the parameters of the action method with values that it parses from the query string, submitted forms, etc. try making sure that somewhere in your message the framework can find something like ParameterName=someValue then you will get someValue passed into the action method's Parameter with the parameterName.

Comment: I finally got it working. We need to be careful about the data type in proper json format("name":"value") format along with type as "POST" and controller action method must be marked with [HTTPPOST] attribute. for ex:- var jsobj=();